# Domain classes and database are out of sync in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I've this weird problem. I have a Grails app in which some database changelog files are missing. Therefore, the database has gone out of sync with the domain classes. I've done some changes in the domain classes. When I try to run the database migration plugin, it is creating a diff betweeb the current domain classes and the database and try to execute all the sql commands that has already been run which is causing error in executing the commands that I want to execute.

Is there is a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can re-create all of the missing changelogs using `dbm-generate-changelog`. This will create changelogs based on the current data model. Then you can use `dbm-changelog-sync` to mark those changelogs as EXECUTED (which will populate the DATABASECHANGELOG table). Once the DATABASECHANGELOG table is in sync with the current data model, you can use `dbm-gorm-diff` to make sure you're not missing any other data model changes.

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/1.4.0/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-changelog-sync.html

NOTE: My answer assumes you're using Grails 2.x and Database Migration plugin 1.4.x, but I believe the process is similar in Grails 3.x with Database Migration Plugin 2.x or 3.x.